# Nodejs Express App shows weird characters for hindi, querying over Sqlite database

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express, utf-8, hindi

The API is made using Nodejs Express. This [Hindi API](https://theislam360.me/api/find/hindi/%E0%A4%86%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%80) is live, showing weird character for Hindi language. It's [English version](https://theislam360.me/api/find/eng/man) displays English results perfectly. Below is the code for Hindi API:

```
app.get("/api/find/hindi/:find",function(request, response)
{
    let db = new sqlite3.Database("./quranDb.db",(err) => {
        if (err){
        console.log("Not connected to sqlite")
        }
        else{
            console.log("Connected to sqlite")
        }
    });

    let sql = `SELECT Surat_ID, Ayat_ID, Surat_Name, Hindi FROM QuranTest`;

db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  rows.forEach((row) => {
    ayats.push(JSON.stringify({Translation: row.Hindi,SuratName: row.Surat_Name,SuratID: row.Surat_ID,AyatNo: row.Ayat_ID}));
  });
  //console.log(ayats);
  Translation="";
  Surat_No="";
  Surah_Name="";
  Ayat_No="";
  try {
  ayats.forEach(function(element) {
    if (element.toLowerCase().includes(request.params.find.toLowerCase())===true)
    {
      counting++;
      element=JSON.parse(element);
      Surah_Name = element.SuratName;
      Ayat_No = element.AyatNo;
      Surah_No = element.SuratID
      Translation = "In Surah "+ element.SuratName+", Ayat Number: "+element.AyatNo+", Quran says: "+ element.Translation;
      const tempObj={
        Surah_No,
        Surah_Name,
        Ayat_No,
        Translation
      }
      parentObj[`result_${counting}`]=tempObj
    }
  if (counting===10){
    throw BreakException
  }

})
  } catch(e) {
    if (e!==BreakException) throw e
  }
  if (counting ===0){
  response.write(JSON.stringify({"speech":"No results found"}))
    }  
  else{
    response.write(JSON.stringify(parentObj))
  }
  response.send();
  counting = 0;
  parentObj={};
});


empty();
function empty() {
    ayats.length = 0;
}

db.close((err) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log('Close the database connection.');
  });

})
```

**Hindi API**

As it can be seen, value of `translation` field is gibberish. It should be in hindi format. The SQL database doesn't have any issue. It shows perfect hindi.
[image]

**English API**
[image]

I also have tried

```
...

}


  else{
    response.write(JSON.stringify(parentObj))
  }
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8"});
  response.send();
  counting = 0;
...
```

but it stops the hindi api from executing. Browser returns an error to refresh the page etc.

Answer (score 0):

I got it right. My mistake was, only telling the header about utf-8 encoding is not enough. `response.write(JSON.stringify(parentObj),"utf-8")` also needs to know, which encoding the body should follow.

```
app.get("/api/find/hindi/:find",function(request, response)
{
    let db = new sqlite3.Database("./quranDb.db",(err) => {
        if (err){
        console.log("Not connected to sqlite")
        }
        else{
            console.log("Connected to sqlite")
        }
    });
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8"}); 
    let sql = `SELECT Surat_ID, Ayat_ID, Surat_Name, Hindi FROM QuranTest`;

db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  rows.forEach((row) => {
    ayats.push(JSON.stringify({Translation: row.Hindi,SuratName: row.Surat_Name,SuratID: row.Surat_ID,AyatNo: row.Ayat_ID}));
  });
  //console.log(ayats);
  Translation="";
  Surat_No="";
  Surah_Name="";
  Ayat_No="";
  try {
  ayats.forEach(function(element) {
    if (element.toLowerCase().includes(request.params.find.toLowerCase())===true)
    {
      counting++;
      element=JSON.parse(element);
      Surah_Name = element.SuratName;
      Ayat_No = element.AyatNo;
      Surah_No = element.SuratID
      Translation = "In Surah "+ element.SuratName+", Ayat Number: "+element.AyatNo+", Quran says: "+ element.Translation;
      const tempObj={
        Surah_No,
        Surah_Name,
        Ayat_No,
        Translation
      }
      parentObj[`result_${counting}`]=tempObj
    }
  if (counting===10){
    throw BreakException
  }

})
  } catch(e) {
    if (e!==BreakException) throw e
  }
  if (counting ===0){
  response.write(JSON.stringify({"speech":"No results found"}),"utf-8")
    }  
  else{
    response.write(JSON.stringify(parentObj),"utf-8")
  }

  response.send();
  counting = 0;
  parentObj={};
});


empty();
function empty() {
    ayats.length = 0;
}

db.close((err) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log('Close the database connection.');
  });

})
```

[image]